# On selection PivotTable 'Fields' go to 'Rows' instead of 'Values'

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I use pivot tables a lot.

But I cannot figure out what make certain filed to go to **Rows**, while others to **Values**.

Normally I always want that whatever field I select go to the **Value** section.

Because some don't, I have to manually drag and drop them every time.

Any way, I can customize this behavior of field?

[Dont want Percentage to go to **Rows**, it should go to **Value** area like Numbers does (shown below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTPia.png)

[This is what I want ideally, field to go to **Value** section, instead of **Rows**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3fOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your data has blanks or spaces or text it the column, Excel won't automatically put it in the VALUES area because it can't be sure that the column is a numerical column.

You need to replace any blanks or empty spaces with a Zero in order to get Excel to automatically put this field into the Value section.

Comment: Thank you. So I need to fill blanks in the number rows.

Comment: Correct. If my answer solved the issue, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in